# Capture SIGINT in Java

Tags: java, signals

What is the best way to capture a kill signal in java without using JNI. I did discover the sun.misc.Signal and the sun.misc.SignalHandler and the warning of the possibility of being removed in the future releases.

Would using JNI to call a c lib be the only option i have?

Comment: Related: [Catching Ctrl+C in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611931/catching-ctrlc-in-java)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The way to handle this would be to register a [shutdown](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) hook. If you use (**SIGINT**) `kill -2` will cause the program to gracefully exit and run the shutdown hooks.

> Registers a new virtual-machine
>   shutdown hook.
>
> The Java virtual machine shuts down in
>   response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

I tried the following test program on OSX 10.6.3 and on `kill -9` it did **NOT** run the shutdown hook, didn't think it would. On a `kill -15` it **DOES** run the shutdown hook every time.

```
public class TestShutdownHook
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Shutdown hook ran!");
            }
        });

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the documented way to write your own [signal handlers](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sun.misc.signalhandler) that aren't shutdown hooks in Java. Be [warned](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html) that the `com.sun.misc` packages and are un-supported and may be changed or go away at any time and probably only exist in the Sun JVM.

Comment: `SIGKILL` (9) is a non catchable signal. That's a Unix design feature.

Comment: The `Runtime` class is `java.lang.Runtime` and exists since JDK 1.0. The `addShutdownHook` method exists [since 1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29). So you can safely rely on them.

Comment: @dolmen read for comprehension, I am warning about the `com.sun` packages, that are mentioned in the question as to not be used.

Comment: `SIGKILL(9)` causes the virtual machine to abort and according to the docs:
`If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29

Comment: Just for the record: `com.sun.*` classes *are* usable and maintained, unlike `sun.*` classes (note the `com.` prefix).

Answer (score 7):

Since at least Java 6, the HotSpot `java` command has had a `-Xrs` flag to disable the JVM signal handlers.

If you use it, you need to implement your own `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGHUP`, and `SIGQUIT` handlers, including one to explicitly call `System.exit()`.

Note: this means the thread dump facility of SIGQUIT is disabled when the `-Xrs` flag is present.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABHDABI (also available on the Windows and Solaris `java` counterparts).

Comment: How should we go about implementing these handlers when we've launched using `-Xrs`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Integrating Signal and Exception Handling](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/signals.html) describing the HotSpot JVM's ability do do signal chaining.  It does involve some C-level trickery though.

Wouldn't `java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)` be enough for your purpose?  These hooks are run by the JVM upon termination, including reception of `SIGINT`, as long as the JVM is able to perform them.

Comment: This is for the entire system shutdown though. While it works in most cases, ideal would be if it worked on the inherited process.