# Prevent shutdown after shutdown hook

Tags: java, application-shutdown, shutdown-hook

So, I should handle Ctrl-C. Ok, I can do that by registering a shutdown hook. And it works well until I want to prevent the shutdown. When Ctrl-C pressed I want to ask the user if he really wants to close the app, and if he isn't, then I want my app to continue running. The problem is I don't know how to prevent shutdown after Ctrl-C pressed.

Any help? :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541475/capture-sigint-in-java

Comment: See (later) answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216172/java-how-could-i-intercept-ctrlc-in-a-cli-application

Comment: Also, http://twit88.com/blog/2008/02/06/java-signal-handling/

Comment: I have a similar problem. In my case I just want to delay or postpone the shutdown until my shutdown hook has finished running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you're in a shutdown hook it's too late.

from [`Runtime.addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

> Once the shutdown sequence has begun it can be stopped only by
>   invoking the
>   [`halt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt%28int%29)
>   method, which forcibly terminates the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't abort a shutdown from inside a shutdown hook. It will proceed.