# How to stop/kill main thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application whose main function is in infinite loop since its based on a polling mechanism.I would like to invoke and kill the main function from outside the application.For starting the application I can directly make a call like : `MyClass.main("parameters")`
but I couldn't find a way to kill the or terminate main function.

Comment: That's a system command . I want to do it from another automated process which first invokes it and then kills it.

Comment: @Harsh Gupta: then you're out of luck. It is impossible for one Java application to stop or kill another without either using a system command or modifying the app to be stopped/killed. There is no API for it.

Comment: @njzk2 `killall` as the name implies will kill any java processes. Just a bad idea. If you want to kill a process kill the right one using the process id ...

Comment: @njzk2 No need for sarcasm. StackOverflow is a public site with a large audience. killall ist almost always the wrong tool, not any reader has >10K reputation and can get the point ...

Comment: @Matteo : sorry if i offended you. I though `killall java` was sufficiently obviously not something you want to actually do, but rather a short representation of `find the process and kill it`, but obviously you are right anyone should be able to read SO without any notion of irony. I remove my sarcastic comment.

Comment: @njzk2 Not offended at all :-). I just see people often killing everything and complaining because then nothing is running... I did not want to seem upset :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make a while loop that checks if a variable is true, and create a method to change the variable. When you want to terminate it, call the method and change it to false.

Comment: "... from outside the application ..." It's unclear to me if the OP really meant from a separate process, but if so, more is needed here.

Comment: maybe he could try to catch some signal - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541475/capture-sigint-in-java

Comment: Yes I have an application which is in infinite loop polling for files and **I cant change the mechanism there** . So if my application is MyApp.java and it has a main function .I want to automate the start and stop/kill the MyApp from another java file Automate.java

Comment: In that case, I don't think its possible. Imaging the havoc that would be caused if outside applications could call methods or change variables. Being purely speculative here, you could perhaps send a ping to the program..

Comment: Shutdownhook will bring down JVM .. that will kill my other processes too isn't it? I want my app to start->stop->continue current process

Answer (score 0):

I would make MyApp a class that implements the Runnable interface.  It would also have some method called hasMoreFile() or isComplete() or something like that.  Then the Automate class would create a Thread and run MyApp in that thread.  Automate would have a loop where it calls MyApp.isComplete() and, if false, sleeps for some specified period of time before checking again.  If MyApp.isComplete() returns true, Automate would send a stop message to MyApp or stop the thread MyApp is running in.