# Is there a way to fix the bug in my code, which uses a shutDownHook to simulate fail-safe behavior?

Tags: java, processbuilder, shutdown-hook

In my Java code, it simply loops some output and then continues to loop it even if we send `CTRL+C` via windows command-line. But issue is that it only works once. After the first iteration of `CTRL+C` it looks like we lose the access to the JVM from within the CMD:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.sql.Date;
import sun.misc.SignalHandler;
import sun.misc.Signal;

import java.io.*;
public class SHTest {  

static int globalVar = 0;

 public static void main ( String[] args ) throws  IOException  , InterruptedException {

        globalVar = Integer.parseInt( args[0] ) ;

        System.out.println ("The Global Var is " + globalVar);
        Runtime.getRuntime ().addShutdownHook ( new Thread () {
            @Override
            public void run () {

            globalVar += 1;
           /* shutdown */
           String[] command = {"C://Program Files//Java//jdk1.7.0_02//bin//java.exe", "SHTest" , "" + globalVar /* + " " + ++globalVar  */ };  //args[0] ... CreateTexts
           ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
           pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

           try {
               Process exec = pb.start(); 
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(exec.getInputStream()));
               String text = null;
           while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(text);
           }

           System.out.println("Process exited with " + exec.waitFor());
           } 

            catch(IOException io) { }

            catch(InterruptedException inter) { }

               // while ( true ) { }
            }
        } );  //end addShutdownHook() 

        //int copyGlobalVar = globalVar;
        while ( true  ) {

            long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Date date = new Date(currentDateTime);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
            String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);


            System.out.println ( "Looping: " + formattedDate + "  :  " + globalVar  );
            Thread.sleep ( 1000 );
        }
    }


    }
```

thanks !

References:

[Sending Signals to a Running JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023520/sending-signals-to-a-running-jvm)

[How can I "intercept" Ctrl+C in a CLI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216172/how-can-i-intercept-ctrlc-in-a-cli-application)

[How to make a Java program that cannot be killed from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506485/how-to-make-a-java-program-that-cannot-be-killed-from-command-line)

Comment: Have you looked into running the java program as a Windows Service?

Comment: @schtever - Hmm not yet - let me look into this - thanks very much !

Comment: Here's a widely used package that I've used with success.  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

Comment: @schtever - Thanks !

Comment: [You can't 'use a shutDownHook to simulate failsafe behavior'.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).

Comment: @EJP  - I think I understand this now... so the shutDownHook function cannot go back once it's in the process. It needs an external library/tool then to achieve what I want. So probably the commons-daemon I think. Or just a type of batch file.  Thank You !!