# Sending a unix signal to a scala application

Tags: java, scala, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending Signals to a Running JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023520/sending-signals-to-a-running-jvm)

I have a scala app running to which i would like to send a "reload" signal, like Ctrl-R from the command line (for now). How do i register a handler for this?
thanks

Comment: Due to java interop, things written [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/) are true for scala too