# Regarding manual termination of the program in eclipse java?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("1 ");
        }
    }
}
```

What this code does is run for infinite till the program is terminated manually for example give the picture below.[image]

What my requirement is when I manually terminate the execution
my  output should be like below

> 1
> 1
> 1
> Program terminated manually
> thank you

The above 2 lines of output after I manually terminate the program.
Why I need this is I am storing the serializable objects in the file. My code flow is when I working on the program there will be a lot of modifications in the object at end of execution I serialize the updated object into the file. So when I terminate the program manually serialization of the updated object is not done. So I need Serialization should be done even at manual termination.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling function when program exits in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687/calling-function-when-program-exits-in-java)

Comment: I don't think there is any way to handle the Eclipse terminate button, it just kills the JVM process immediately.

Comment: Note: running code from within Eclipse is only intended for testing. If you run the java program from the command line you can use the shutdown hook to deal with Ctrl+C termination.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hook to the shutdown event:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
        //Do something here
    }));
```

Edit: This doesn't work with eclipse, according to greg-449

Comment: The terminate button in Eclipse forces the program to abort immediately, the shutdown hook is not run.

Comment: Sorry I am not really familiar with eclipse, it worked in Idea, so I thought it would work here too. Thank you.